# Using INTERSECTS to make a create view statement in sql

Tags: sql, view, create-table, create-view

I am creating a SQL create view statement and I am having trouble with my last statement that I have to write. For this statement I have to use intersect to get people who are older than 30 and taller than 65 inches. The exact details of the query are as follows

- Write a query that returns the first and last name of all people listed in body composition table who are older than 30 years old. Then modify your query to use INTERSECTS to return all people who are older than 30 and are taller than 65 inches.

I tried writing this view statement using intersect and inner join to get the names from a different table, but I get an error when I try and run the program. The error that I get is

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WHERE"
>   LINE 11: WHERE b.height = 65;

I am not going to post my full program, just this create view statement so the line numbers will be off. I am going to post my code and then the two tables that I am using to create this view statement, and hopefully someone can help me fix this error. Thanks in advance.

```
CREATE VIEW intersectt AS
   SELECT 
      a.fname, a.lname
   FROM 
      what.person as a
   INNER JOIN 
      what.body_composition as b ON a.pid = b.pid
   WHERE 
      b.age > 30

   INTERSECT

   SELECT 
      a.fname, a.lname
   FROM 
      what.person as a
   INNER JOIN 
      what.body_composition as b 
   WHERE 
      b.height = 65;
```

Here are the two tables

Table `what.body_composition`:

```
 Column |  Type   | Modifiers 
--------+---------+-----------
 pid    | integer | not null
 height | integer | not null
 weight | integer | not null
 age    | integer | not null
```

and table `what.person`:

```
 Column |         Type          |                      Modifiers                      
--------+-----------------------+-----------------------------------------------
 pid    | integer               | not null default nextval('person_pid_seq'::reg class)
 uid    | integer               | 
 fname  | character varying(25) | not null
 lname  | character varying(25) | not null
```

Comment: You don't have an `on` clause in the second subquery.

Comment: thanks a lot! Is there a way to view what I create? because I go into psql and run my sql program \i what.sql and then it just shows that the table was created, I want to see whats in the table

Comment: Sp_help tablename to view table schema or view content

Answer (score 0):

You are missing ON clause in the second query

```
   CREATE VIEW intersectt AS
   SELECT a.fname, a.lname
   FROM what.person as a
   INNER JOIN     what.body_composition as b
   ON a.pid = b.pid
   AND b.age > 30
   INTERSECT
   SELECT a.fname, a.lname
   FROM what.person as a
   INNER JOIN what.body_composition as b
   ON a.pid = b.pid
   AND b.height = 65
```